# could not use custom templatetags in Django 2.0

Tags: django, django-template-filters, django-2.0

I'm using `Django 2.0`.

I have written few custom template tags to use in the template inside
`notes/templatetags/note_tags.py` file where `notes` is app directory

I have written few custom tags inside this file

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
from notepad.utils import simplify_text
from notes.models import Note, ColorLabels

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='note_simplify')
@stringfilter
def note_simplify(value):
    return simplify_text(value)


@register.filter(name='default_color_label')
def default_color_label():
    default_label = ColorLabels.objects.filter(default=True).first()
    print(default_label.value)
    return default_label
```

and inside the `template` file, I have loaded the tag as

```
{% load note_tags %}
```

I'm able to use the first tag `note_simplify` but second tag `default_color_label` is not being called. I'm using both tags in the same file. One for modifying the passed data and another to simply print something

```
# modify the note.content
<p>{{ note.content|truncatechars:200|note_simplify }}</p>

# to print some value
{{ default_color_label.value }}
```

I have also restared server many times.

**Is there something wrong?** Why the tag is not being called in template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `simple_tag` here, if you want an object in template.

```
@register.simple_tag  
def default_color_label():
    default_label = ColorLabels.objects.filter(default=True).first()
    return default_label
```

And in HTML you can use it.

```
{% default_color_label as variable %}
{{ variable.value }}
```

> **Note:** You have defined `filter` not tag and also you are using it incorrectly.
>   template filters are always used with pipe operator.
>   `{{ somevalue|default_color_label }}`

**UPDATE**

> `assignment_tag` **Deprecated since version 1.9** `simple_tag` can now store results in a
>   template variable and should be used instead.

Comment: It is giving `'Library' object has no attribute 'assignment_tag'` error

Comment: The assignment_tag decorator was deprecated in 1.9 and removed in 2.0. Use `simple_tag` instead - everything wise remains the same.